# Resizing an iframe to fit content on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Could somebody please show me how to fit an iframe to the content within? I have this because I am using one iframe on my website that when a link is clicked displays different pages and I would love for the iframe to fit to the content within as at the moment the iframe is too long for some page's content but too short for other page's content and it cuts the page off.

I do not really have much code to show which is relevant or that will be any help, however in line with the rules on Stack below is the code that I have so far.

I have seen some questions on here regarding the same thing but none that I really understand.

```
<iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://airforceadvice.com/PCS" name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
      </iframe>
```

Comment: I know but that would not help in this situation, as you move around the secondary site within the iframe the content height changes it almost a website within an iframe on a website. If you get me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your head section

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe(obj) {
        obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

And change your iframe to this:

```
<iframe name="Stack" src="http://stackoverflow.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="iframe" onload='javascript:resizeIframe(this);' />
```

Is this what you're looking for?